# Decode nested JSON value in Elm (0.18)

Tags: json, elm

Given the following types:

```
type alias Wrapper =
    { data : Data }

type alias Data =
    { name : String }
```

And the following JSON:

```
{"data": {"name": "Keith"}}
```

How can I write a decoder which will allow me to turn an HTTP response into an instance of the `Wrapper` type alias?

I've tried a number of approaches using the core libraries, Json.Decode.Pipeline and Json.Decode.Extra, without finding a workable solution.

Here's my latest attempt:

```
dataDecoder =
    succeed Data
        |> andMap (field "name" Decode.string)

wrapperDecoder =
    succeed Wrapper
        |> andMap (field "data" dataDecoder)
```

Which results in:

> BadPayload "Expecting an object with a field named `name` but instead got: {\"data\":{\"name\":\"foo\"}}" { status = { code = 200, message = "OK" }, headers = Dict.fromList [("cache-control","max-age=0, private, must-revalidate"),("content-type","application/json; charset=utf-8")], url = "http://localhost:5000//users/foo", body = "{\"data\":{\"name\":\"foo\"}}" }

EDIT:

This wound up being an end-user problem. I *was* passing the correct decoder to `Http.post`, but `Http.send` wasn't actually calling the function wrapping `Http.post`. Doh.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

Your decoders work fine against your example input, but the error message you are getting leads me to believe you are trying to use `dataDecoder` in your Http call rather than `wrapperDecoder`, since the error message is looking for a field named `name`.

While `succeed` and `andMap` *can* be used to construct your decoder, you can get by with `map`:

```elm
dataDecoder : Decoder Data
dataDecoder =
    Decode.map Data (field "name" string)

wrapperDecoder : Decoder Wrapper
wrapperDecoder =
    Decode.map Wrapper (field "data" dataDecoder)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the vanilla solution. Unfortunately, I am passing `wrapperDecoder` to `Http.post`. e.g. `Http.post apiUrl body wrapperDecoder`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the wrapper/wrapper-decoder, or do I need the extra wrapper type-alias?

Answer (score 1):

As Chad Gilbert wrote, your decoders are fine: https://ellie-app.com/kDX99XRbta1/0

To doublecheck, add type annotations to your decoders:

```
dataDecoder : Decoder Data
dataDecoder = ...

wrapperDecoder : Decoder Wrapper
wrapperDecoder = ...
```

If you're really using `wrapperDecoder` (`Http.post apiUrl body wrapperDecoder`), there's one more possibility for an error: that your API endpoint returns data with a different shape, something like:

```
{"data": {"data": {"name": "foo"}}}
```

Can you doublecheck this? (in Chrome's Web Inspector etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the working sample! I can confirm that I'm passing `wrapperDecoder` to `Http.post` _and_ that my API is returning data in the expected shape. `curl -X POST http://localhost:5000/users/foo => {"data":{"name":"foo"}}`. I will attempt to clean up my code and add it to my question to rule out any doubts.